# How can I wait for multiple Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm working with some old code and I'm trying to return results for two arrays of promises.

So basically body contains `first` and `second` which are arrays of ids. I know that the below code works for a small array of of 1 to 5 ids, but if I were to do a few hundred, would the resolve fire before I get the hundred of results from both promise arrays?

```
 const doSomething = (body) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const promisesOne = body.first.map((id) => 
        doSomethingOne(id)
      );

      const promisesTwo = body.second.map((id) => 
        doSomethingTwo(id)
      );

      let response = {
        first: {}
        second: {}
        headers: 'mock headers'
      };

      Promise.all(promisesOne).then((results) => {
        response.first = results;
      });

      Promise.all(promisesTwo).then((results) => {
        response.second = results;
      });

      resolve(response);
  });
};
```

Also I won't be able to refactor this to async/await as this codebase does not use it.

Comment: FYI your code always returns `resolve()` before you get results, no matter how large your arrays are

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: I would if I could... Unfortunately, it isn't my codebase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> would the resolve fire before I get the ... results from both promise arrays?

Yes, absolutely because you aren't waiting for them to resolve.

Simply wrap the two `Promise.all()` promises in another `Promise.all()` to wait for everything then create the final object you want.

```js
const doSomething = (body) => {
  return Promise.all([
    Promise.all(body.first.map(doSomethingOne)),
    Promise.all(body.second.map(doSomethingTwo)),
  ]).then(([first, second]) => ({
    first,
    second,
    headers: "mock headers",
  }));
};
```

---

You could make this generic by creating a map of `body` property names to their corresponding mapping function. For example

```js
const mappers = {
  first: doSomethingOne,
  second: doSomethingTwo,
};

const doSomething = (body) => {
  return Promise.all(
    Object.entries(mappers).map(([key, mapper]) =>
      Promise.all(body[key].map(mapper)).then((data) => ({ [key]: data }))
    )
  )
  .then((results) => Object.assign({ headers: "mock headers" }, ...results));
};
```

Comment: Your second snippet is neat indeed, but - unlike the others - does not run the `doSomethingOne` tasks in parallel with the `doSomethingTwo` tasks

Comment: @Bergi I've removed it now. After making it parallel, it didn't look much better than the non-async alternative

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not work at the moment - the `resolve(response)` will run before either of the `Promise.all`s are done.

First, refactor your `.first` and `.second` (etc) properties so that they're arrays, rather than unique string properties. Then, it'll be easy to `.map` them with two `Promise.all`s - one to wait for an individual array to fulfill, and an outer one to wait for all arrays to fulfill.

The same thing should be done for the `doSomethingOne` etc functions - to make the code easy to work with, use an array of functions instead of having many standalone identifiers.

Also, there's no need for the explicit Promise construction antipattern.

```
const doSomethings = [
  doSomethingOne, // define these functions here
  doSomethingTwo,
];

const doSomething = (body) => Promise.all(
  body.arrayOfArraysOfIds.map(
    (arr, i) => Promise.all(
      arr.map(id => doSomethings[i](id))
    )
  )
)
  .then((results) => ({
    headers: 'mock headers',
    results,
  });
```